# How can I make this offset binary search return None if the item is not found?

Tags: python, offset, binary-search

I have to make a binary search using an offset, so there's no left or right variable. I need to make it return None if the item isn't found, but for whatever reason I'm stumped as to how I can do that. I know you can do

```
if right >= left:
    #search function here
else: return None
```

But I don't have those variables and it doesn't work with array[mid:] >= array[:mid]

Here is the function

```
def binary_search(array, item, offset=0):
    mid = int(len(array)/2) #make mid an int so it truncates

    if item == array[mid]: #if the item is at mid, we're done
        return mid + offset
    elif item > array[mid]: #if the item is bigger than the item at mid, go to right side of array
        return binary_search(array[mid:], item, offset+mid) #add the mid value to offset since we're going right
    else: #otherwise, the value is smaller and we go to the left side of the array
        return binary_search(array[:mid], item, offset) #leave offset the same
```

I've tried a bunch of different things but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe these facts and use them to tweak your algorithm:

- As written, your function will always return an integer, because `mid + offset` is an integer.  If you want to return a `None`, you'll need a bare `return` somewhere (the `if`/`elif`/`else` chain will never fall through).
- You'll need a halting condition for the recursion somewhere.  You do have one currently (after the comment "if the item is at mid, we're done").  However, *you will need another, different, `return` for handling the case when the value is not present*.
- If you receive an empty array as input, the `mid` will be calculated as index 0.  Does that seem right...?
- Slicing `array[mid:]` includes the item at index `mid`.  Slicing at `array[:mid]` does *not* include the item at index `mid`.  Look for any logical overlap in the three branches of your if/elif/else.

Comment: The closest thing I've gotten was adding if mid ==0: return None after the mid calculation. This works unless I'm searching for the leftmost item, which will have a mid value of zero, returning None.

As for your fourth point, the offset value is thrown off if I slice at array[mid+1:], so I think I have to keep it there.

Comment: Found a solution by adding <if len(array) == 1 and array[0] != item:
                                                   return None> just after the mid calculation. 

I've been staring at this screen for too long today lol thank you!